# How to extract text from Image using Cordova?

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm using **Cordova** to develop mobile application for extracting text from image. I wanted to know about the any plugin or some api available in Cordova or in Javascript to achieve this.

Please me out

Answer (score 1):

Consider using an OCR plugin which are available in Cordova

Example:
http://phonegap-plugins.com/plugins/albertarvesu/image-scanner-cordova-plugin

Complete list:
http://phonegap-plugins.com/plugins/

Alternatively you can use a JavaScript OCR library, for example Ocrad.js